# Javascript code in Java - ReferenceError: "jQuery" is not defined

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I run javascript code in java. My goal is find coordinates of elements in HTML page. If I run my code I get `ReferenceError: "jQuery" is not defined in <eval>` . I tried add var `$ = jQuery;` to my script but it didnt help. At this line I get the ReferenceError. I'm beginner in javascript. Can anybody help, please? Thank you very much!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException, IOException, Exception {

    ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
    engine.eval(new FileReader("script.js"));

    Invocable invocable = (Invocable) engine;
    Object result = invocable.invokeFunction("fun2");
    System.out.println(result);
}
}
```

My script.js is

```
var funkce = function() {
    var elem = $("div#some_container_id h1")
    var elem_offset = elem.offset();


    var elem_height = elem.height();
    var elem_width = elem.width();

     return elem_height;
}
var $ = jQuery;
var fun2 = $(document).ready(funkce);
```

Comment: Do you actually have JQuery included somewhere?

Comment: I added jquery 3.1.1 librabry... Do you mean this?

Comment: You'll need to actually include the file though. Simply having the JQuery script in a certain folder isn't enough. You'll probably need to look over the Java library documentation to see how to do that. I've never run JS via Java before.

Comment: Which file, please? I thought it is enough. Because if I run my script just with print('Hello'); so this is working...

Comment: You need to look up how to include JS libraries using the ScriptEngine

Comment: You need to `eval` the jQuery file before you `eval` the `script.js` file.

Comment: I can run JS code since Java 8, but I think my problem is in my javascript file...Maybe...I don't know :D

Comment: Just like a Java program can be multiple files so can a Javascript program. In your Java code, you've loaded  your script with this `engine.eval(new FileReader("script.js"));`, you need to do the same with the jquery file: `engine.eval(new FileReader("jquery.js"));`, and that needs to be done *before* you load "script.js"

Comment: @4castle jQuery file? should I use somehow `engine.eval(jQuery);` ?

Comment: @DanielHerbrych jQuery is also a script just like yours. jQuery is not native to JavaScript. Would you find it wierd that the engine did not recognized the `funkce` function if you did not load your own script file? No, well it's the same for jQuery.

Comment: you can go to this url: http://jquery.com/download/ and download a file called jquery-3.1.1.js. That is the file you should call `engine.eval(jquery-3.1.1.js);` on.

Comment: Keep in mind, your code will never work. jquery depends on a DOM being available. The DOM is typically implemented by the browser. For instance the `document` object is part of the DOM api. jQuery uses the DOM api behind the scenes. Since this isn't available in your environment (i.e. the script engine instance you are using), your code won't function.

Comment: Thank you guys, I tried to download jquery-3.1.1.js, copy it to folder with other files and use `engine.eval(jquery-3.1.1.js);`. This didnt work, so I tried `engine.eval(new FileReader("jquery.js"));` because this file is in jar file: meta-inf/resources/webjars/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js ... I dont know what I am doing wrong... Anyway, thank you all very much :)

Comment: @mangotang Hmmmm.... Okay, thank you. That is bad for me. I want to find coordinates of elements, so I thought I can get all elements with this code from HTML page.

Comment: @mangotang Do you know how to find coordinates of tags rendered by the browser? For example, some <div> blocks and their coordinates in web browser. Or other choice is take only particular div block and then render this block in web browser. Thank you!

Comment: The only way I can think of to do this is to actually run your Javascript code in a browser (like FireFox, IE or Chrome). These environments (in the browser) will have a DOM that jquery can use to determine the coordinates of the tags in your page. jquery's api includes functions for finding the "top, left" coordinates, and "width, height" of tags in the page. You should consult the jquery docs.

Comment: @mangotang Thank you a lot! :-) Honestly, you helped to me. Thanks again.

Comment: @Daniel Herbrych no problem Daniel, good luck with your project.